# Odoo 10 - How to get the job_id of the user_id

Tags: odoo-10

How to get the job_id of the user_id linked to the employee_id

user_id_job = fields.Char(? string='User Job')

Comment: Can you please explain it more?

Comment: user_id = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('employee_id','=',your employee id)])

Comment: @LisaKain Please post full example!

Answer (score 2):

i just got the answer

```
<t t-foreach="request.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', user.id)])" t-as="obj">
<t t-esc="obj.job_id.name"/>
</t>
```